# Golang large memory usage when inserting in postgres

Tags: database, postgresql, go

I'm using goland standard library database/sql to insert an attachment into a bytea column in postgres

```
        _, err = tx.Exec(`
            INSERT INTO
                election_news_attachments(news_id, file_name, file_type, data, thumbnail)
            VALUES
                ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5)
            `,
            newsID,
            attachments[i].FileName,
            attachments[i].FileType,
            attachments[i].Data,
            attachments[i].Thumbnail,
        )
```

And the problem here is the attachments[i].Data which is []byte data of size 70MB.
And once this Exec is called it takes this data and starts using a lot of RAM.
It's like it takes that data and makes 10 duplicates of it

I'm using this library to check the RAM usage https://pkg.go.dev/runtime#MemStats

[the memory image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4gA5.png)

the first row is before the Exec function is called and the second is after the Exec function

I know that it's not a great thing to place big files like this into a column but this is not something I decide. But it is something I need to implement...

So if anyone knows the cause for this much RAM usage by the Exec function and is there a way around it. The way around it could be could be a different library or some approach.
I was thinking about placing it in a temporary file and calling read_binary_file inside postgres and this works amazing locally but on production the database and backend are on different servers so this is not an option.
And do you maybe think this RAM issue is a problem that should be created as an issue on the library or is it just a thing that should not be done by passing big files

Comment: without more detailed observation results out of your program, it is hard to understand the root cause of your problem.

Comment: not sure what you mean by "more detailed observation results " because there is no result the goal is to insert big []byte inside the database with the Exec function and that is done it works. But for some reason that []byte with the size of  70MB inside the Exec function consumes 1GB of RAM to pass that data to the database. And this is a problem because what if the data is even bigger like 500MB that would take up insane amount of ram for a single database insert

Comment: How about saving Data in external storage like S3 or in file system like, `storage/attachments/`? I think there is extra operations converting bytes to consumable format so it takes ram. Also as I understand You're going to serve file using go methods which will also consume ram when You'll read it from db. So I recommend to store file contents in external location (not in db).

Comment: In addition to my previous comment, if You will save it in file system or in s3 You'll get ability stream file using go channels. Otherwise You'll have to get whole data to memory then serve.

Comment: Although storing files in separate storage is a good option, if you still need to store it in an SQL database, I would suggest 1) debugging the code and finding the memory consumption reason and 2) use profiling tools like pprof to find the largest memory allocation places by getting the memory heap: https://pkg.go.dev/net/http/pprof

Comment: TotalAlloc is a counter that never decreases and does not represent memory usage. See [the docs](https://pkg.go.dev/runtime#MemStats).